# how to change images on different button clicks in wordpress/elementor

Tags: wordpress, filter, tabs, gallery, elementor

i need a help regarding developing 3 column section, in which the mid column is for image. and left and right columns have buttons like 5 on right and 5 on left respectively and i want to change the image on each button when user clicks on it. im using elementor builder
please guide me if I can do it through any plugin or html or javascript. i can add the reference image so you can exactly understand what I need. thanks in advance.

[this is the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZhrP.png)
it can be a widget if it is let me know as im not much into coding.

Comment: Please share the code. What at least you tried.

Comment: i have added this code, and it somehow works, showblock is a button, and hideblock is a hidden image that will appear. but now i need it to repeat it for multiple images and multiple buttons. also, i want first button image to be appear by default on page load.
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   
  $('#showBlock').click(function(e) {
        $('#hiddenBlock').show("slow");
 
    $('#showBlock2').click(function(e) {
        $('#hiddenBlock2').show("slow");
       $('#hiddenBlock').hide("slow");
  
    });
  

  });
});

Comment: Share your HTML code as well.

Comment: bro its elementor, not html, so i just add buttons on each column which has a class of showblock, and the mid column has image widget, which has a class of hiddenblock

Comment: You have to give every hidden block to the one unique class name and one same

Comment: same for hide and unique for show right?

Comment: thanks mate it works, please let me know how could i make first one to be active on page load?

Comment: Yes for hiding and unique for the show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `hiddenBlock` class to every video or image element. and hide all and display the first element by CSS.

CSS

```
function hide_hiddenBlock(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hiddenBlock{display: none;}
        .hiddenBlock1{display: show;}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_hiddenBlock', 10, 1 );
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function show_video_based_on_button_click(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ){ 
            
            // hide every element that has a hidden block class and then show accordingly.

            $('.hiddenBlock').hide("slow");

            $('#showBlock1').click( function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock1').show("slow"); 
            }); 

            $('#showBlock2').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock2').show("slow");
            }); 

            $('#showBlock3').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock3').show("slow");
            }); 

            $('#showBlock4').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock4').show("slow");
            });

            $('#showBlock5').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock5').show("slow");
            }); 

            $('#showBlock6').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock6').show("slow");
            }); 

            $('#showBlock7').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock7').show("slow");
            }); 

            $('#showBlock8').click(function(e) { 
                $('.hiddenBlock8').show("slow");
            }); 

        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_video_based_on_button_click', 10, 1 );
```